# How can I make the width of MaterialTextView wrap_content but no larger than MaterialButton in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmn"
        android:textSize="17.5sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="do something"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

How can I make the width of `MaterialTextView` `wrap_content` but no larger than `MaterialButton` in `ConstraintLayout`?

I did that in `XML` above, But the `MaterialTextView` Not `wrap_content` it seems like `match_parent`.

I watched this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099951/how-to-make-view-wrap-content-but-not-larger-than-with-constraintlayout) and that was not helpful for me or maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the width of `MaterialTextView` to wrap to its content but no larger than `MaterialButton` you need to add the below attributes in your MaterialTextView xml layout: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"`.

Example is like the below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:text="Small Text"
   android:background="@color/teal_200"
   android:textSize="17.5sp"
   app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Small Text:**

[image: small_text]

**Long Text:**

[image: long_text]

Comment: I solved the problem 1 hour ago but don't understand what `layout_constrainedWidth` can do, Also Could you look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893697/trying-to-understand-constraints-in-constraintlayout) about `ConstraintLayout` if you know the solution.